# Does a class inherit an interface or implement an interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Since C# uses same syntax for inheritance and implementation, i.e. ':'. Do we say a class implements an interface or inherits an interface? Can a class inherit anything ever from an interface?

Comment: Class implements the interface. There is nothing which can be inherited from interface.

Comment: An Interface is just a container with virtual members and no implementation so there's nothing to inherit here

Comment: No, you always implement an interface and inherit from a base class. C# syntax has nothing to do with it, this is basic OOP.

Comment: Its a good question after C# 8.0 implements the default-interface-members... they said "[...]Existing implementations inherit the default implementation.[...]"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-members

Answer (score 1):

An interface has nothing to *inherit** so a class would *implement* the interface.

*This is going to change slightly in C# version 8 where we will get [default interface implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md) but for the sake of sanity, I would imagine we will still use "implements" rather than "inherits"

Answer (score 1):

Classes cannot inherit from an interface, since an interface is by definition empty: it only dictates the mandatory implementation of certain members.

From the [MSDN about interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/):

> "An interface contains definitions for a group of
>   related functionalities that a class or a struct can implement."

For example:

```
interface IWritable {
    void Write();
}
```

The code above does only establish the need to have a `Write()` method in all classes that implement it.

Now the *tricky* part. You can think of an interface as a pure abstract class, i.e., it does only define methods without implementation. In other programming languages such as C++ (which incidentally supports multiple inheritance, hence there is no "need" to any distinction), these classes are inherited. Moreover, you can define default implementations for these methods, or even constants. In fact, this is going to be allowed in C# as well.

So the line dividing "implements" and "extends" or "inherits" gets blurry as we think more in how it is implemented and the functionalities that it will provide in the future.

In terms of design, though, it is definitely an implementation.

Further reading in the [MSDN: interfaces reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface).

Comment: "certain methods" should be changed to "certain members - methods, properties, events or indexers." +1, though, for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Zohar Peled, changed.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can implement multiple interfaces and a Class can Inherit from no more than one class at a time.

Comment: Note that it's only the C# spec that restricts the language to only allowing a single class to inherit from. Multiple inheritance is present in many other languages.

Comment: I totally agreed with you.  My answer is based on his question which refers to c#

Answer (score 0):

Classes always Implement the interfaces and never inherit anything from interfaces but interfaces can inherit other interfaces.

Let see the below example, Here I have defined two Interfaces **ISum** and **IMinus** respectively.

**Inheritance of Interfaces:** ISum is inherited in IMinus.

**Implementation of Interfaces:** IMinus is implemented in FooClass.

```
public interface ISum
{
    int Sum(int a, int b);
}

public interface IMinus : ISum
{
    int Minus(int a, int b);
}

public class FooClass: IMinus
{
    public int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int Minus(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```